# Qt creator compile error "cannot find uic.exe from msvc 2012 path"

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

i am new to developing GUI using qt creator. When trying to run a widget c++ program i got this error on the compile output terminal.

```
16:37:20: Running steps for project gui...
16:37:20: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
16:37:21: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\bin\uic.exe ..\gui\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
'C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\bin\uic.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Users\JOSEPH\SkyDrive\Documents\qt\build gui-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [ui_mainwindow.h] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\JOSEPH\SkyDrive\Documents\qt\build-gui-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
16:37:24: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project gui (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.0 MSVC2012 OpenGL 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
16:37:24: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

have checked the given path for the uic.exe which i cannot find there. is there how i can download the exe file and paste to the path?

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: I used the online installer for qt windows version

Comment: Broken installation? Try reinstalling...

Comment: Thanks The problem should be with the msvc 2012 is there no way I can download that alone

Comment: Did you ever get the answer for this? It happened to me too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused due to compatibility issue with the msvc 2012.

All I did was download the offline installer of Qt for msvc 2013. Then reinstalled the program.

Thanks for the help and sugesstions