# QT: uic doesn't generate header for .ui file

Tags: qt, uic

I am using QT 5.10 and [Qt Visual Studio Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2015) (for Visual Studio 2015).
I want to create a dll that contains a class which inherits from `QDialog`. So I created QT Class Library project and added an .ui file to it. But when I try to compile the project, I receive this error message: `Error starting process \bin\uic.exe: Не удается найти указанный файл` (this means "cannot find the file specified"). I guess that uic cannot find `ui_<.ui filename>.h` file. It is not automatically generated by some reason. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153760/qt-creator-compile-error-cannot-find-uic-exe-from-msvc-2012-path)

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that the problem is with compatibility with MSVC2015, because QT 5.10 suits for it. Indeed there is a folder named "msvc2015" in QT 5.10.1 directory.

Comment: Have you set the Qt path in the settings for the VS Tools?

Comment: Of course, I have. Other QT projects compile fine. The problem appears when I create a QT Class Library and add an .ui file to it.